# Using setupbackend and pdfpageattr together via ConTeXt

Tags: pdftex, luatex, context

Is it possible to use `setupbackend` and `pdfpageattr` together via ConTeXt?

I was able to use `setupbackend` alone via ConTeXt (LuaTeX). Got the result as expected.

I was able to use `pdfpageattr` alone via ConTeXt (pdfTeX). Got the result as expected.

However, combining those two together I couldn't compile the code without a problem.

If compiled via ConTeXt (pdfTeX), an error states: Undefined control sequence. \setupbackend

If compiled via ConTeXt (LuaTeX), no error but `pdfpageattr` settings not affected with result. For example, the result with TrimBox is not [81.6378 96.9449 513.6378 744.9449]

```
\setupbackend
[format=PDF/X-3:2002,
profile=ps_cmyk.icc,
intent=ps_cmyk.icc]  

\pdfpageattr{/TrimBox [ 81.6378 96.9449 513.6378 744.9449]}
```

If it is not possible to combine those two macros together, is there an alternative way to set PDF/X-3:2002, insert ps_cmyk.icc and set TrimBox together via ConTeXt?

Comment: `\pdfpageattr` is removed from LuaTeX as of v0.85: at the very least you'll need to use a different input syntax.

Comment: @Joseph Wright, What input syntax can I use for TrimBox via ConTeXt (LuaTeX)?

Comment: The best information I found was at [PDF Boxes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDF_Boxes) However, I don't see how I can enter 4 parameters. For example [81.6378 96.9449 513.6378 744.9449]

Comment: It may be better to ask this question on the context mailing list.